# igraph reorder vertices to sorted order

Tags: r, graph, igraph

currently, I read in a graph from an edgelist as follows:

```
>> require(igraph)  # i have igraph 1.1.0
>> g1 <- read_graph(graphname, format='ncol')
>> V(g1)
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 38 40 42 44 46 47 48 49 50 52 56 57 58
 [50] 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 67 68 41 69 43 53 37 39 45 51 54 55 66 70
```

As you can see, the vertex ordering is completely wrong, despite the fact that the vertices have incredibly, incredibly basic naming convention (they are all just integers). This is incredibly problematic, because the ordering of the `get.adjacency` function in igraph (returning me a 70x70 matrix) depends on the ordering of the vertices in `V(g1)`, so when I try to compare to some `g2` with the same set of vertices, they are similarly in a ridiculously nonsensical ordering (yet distinct from the one here) leading to inconsistent graph vertices in the sample of graphs I have despite them all having the same vertex labels. Is there a way to correct this issue, such that I can easily reorder the vertices in my graph so that the resulting adjacency matrices have sensible orderings?

EDIT: note I have already tried permuting the vertices with the `permute.vertices` function:

```
>> gtest <- permute.vertices(g1, as.numeric(V(g1)))  # permute vertex ids by the ordering returned by V()
>> V(gtest)  # too bad it doesn't work...
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 38 40 42 44 46 47 48 49 50 52 56 57 58
 [50] 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 67 68 41 69 43 53 37 39 45 51 54 55 66 70
```

I managed to get it working when I instead read my graph in as:

```
>> g1 <- read_graph(graphname, format='ncol', predef=1:70)
>> V(g1)
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
[50] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
```

But this seems a bit ludicrous if this really is the *only* way to do it. Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Thanks!